# Implicit cast to void* in ternary operator?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, conditional-operator

I know typed pointers can be implicitly cast to `void*` when passed to a function expecting a `void*` argument, but I didn't expect to see it in the ternary op (at least I think that's what's going on).

Consider this simplified code:

```
int * dude() {
    float * f = NULL;
    int * i = NULL;
    return (0 ? f : i);  // pointer type mismatch in conditional expression (good: this is what I want)
}
```

But if I cast `i` to `void*`:

```
int * dude() {
    float * f = NULL;
    int * i = NULL;
    return (0 ? f : (void*)i);  // no error!  it suddenly likes f?  or is f being optimized out?
}
```

I'll go one step further and intentionally return `f`:

```
int * dude() {
    float * f = NULL;
    int * i = NULL;
    return (1 ? f : (void*)i);  // again no error... is f being converted to void*?
}
```

I expected an error in both the 2nd & 3rd examples, but I don't get one.  Can someone explain what is going on here?  Thanks!

Comment: tagged C++, but the answers are likely still relevant for non-class types: [C++ : Ternary Operator (Conditional Operator) and its Implicit Type Conversion Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251419/c-ternary-operator-conditional-operator-and-its-implicit-type-conversion-r)

Comment: Terminology nitpick: there are implicit *conversions* but no implicit *casts*.  A cast is by definition an operation involving a typecast operator.

Comment: @underscore_d the accepted answer at your link tantalizingly says "pointer conversions are performed to convert them to a common type"... too bad it doesn't go into more detail (what conversions are performed when, what common type is chosen, etc)

Comment: Ah yes, @JohnBollinger, good catch

Comment: Yet another of the many reasons to avoid `?:` unless you have very specialized requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard explicitly says that if both operands of the conditional operator are pointers and one is `void*` (not including a null-pointer constant), then the result is `void*`. From C11 6.5.15/6:

> **If both the second and third operands are pointers** or one is a null pointer constant and the other is a pointer, the result type is a pointer to a type qualified with all the type qualifiers of  the  types  referenced  by  both  operands.  Furthermore,  if  both  operands  are  pointers  to compatible types or to differently qualified versions of compatible types, the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type; if one operand is a null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand; otherwise, **one operand is  a  pointer  to void or  a  qualified  version  of void, in which  case  the  result  type  is  a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of void.**

Comment: Right.  (And that "not including a null-pointer constant" is quite relevant because I get the exact same behavior if the float & int ptrs were initialised to something other than NULL.)

Comment: @textral It doesn't matter how they were initialized - the variables aren't null pointer constants in any case. The point is that putting `(void*)0` directly inside the conditional wouldn't make the conditional have a `void*` result type.

Comment: you are right again: I just changed (void*)i in my 2nd example to (void*)0 and got "return from incompatible pointer type" on that line.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: the problem is that it is missing the warning even in the more complex example https://godbolt.org/z/aaerr4. IMO it does not answer anything

Comment: @0___________ Both examples have one operand of type `void*` which makes the result `void*`. The only thing you changed is the first operand which is irrelevant to the type.

Comment: @interjay it does not matter https://godbolt.org/z/rze5ds

Comment: @0___________ That seems to work exactly as expected and as specified in my answer. If you have an issue with my answer try to clearly state what it is because your comments are far too vague.